# aws s3 java sdk list objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk

I have a structure as so:

```
common/test/v20170522/part-0001.snappy
common/test/v20170522/part-0002.snappy
common/test/v20170522/part-0003.snappy
common/test/v20170522/part-0004.snappy
common/test/v20170622/part-0001.snappy
common/test/v20170622/part-0002.snappy
common/test/v20170622/part-0003.snappy
common/test/v20170622/part-0004.snappy
```

There are a lot more version folders with a lot more files in them. I basically want a listing of all of the folders in the `test/common` folder: so `v20170522, v20170622, etc`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest();
listObjectsRequest.setBucketName("common");
listObjectsRequest.setPrefix("test/");
listObjectsRequest.setDelimiter("/");
```

This returns to me just the files that are in the `common/test` folder and not the folders. When I remove the delimiter, I get all of the subfiles of all the folders. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: getCommonPrefixes()?

Comment: Yup that was it! Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad it helped. Have added as an answer with a little more context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to know that S3 is not a regular file system and that the list operation works a little differently to what you might expect.

When invoking listObjects, you specify:

- `prefix` which limits results to only those keys that begin with the specified prefix
- `delimiter` which causes listObjects to roll up all keys that share a common prefix into a single summary list result

You should find the 'folders' in the returned common prefixes, accessible via [getCommonPrefixes()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/VersionListing.html#getCommonPrefixes--).

For more, see [Listing Keys using Prefix and Delimiter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html).